# AWS CodePipeline: Expected to execute only respective branch's codepipeline

Tags: aws-codepipeline

I am working on AWS CodePipeline and facing some weird issues.
The repository branch structure is like this:
main -> dev -> developer-001

I have configured the CodePipeline for "dev" branch. So ideally, the codepipeline must be run when some changes are pushed/merged into "dev" branch only. But if I pushed/merged the code on "developer-001" branch even though the "dev" codepipeline gets executed.

What's wrong going here? Please give some solutions or clarify the things/concepts if I am missing somewhere.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your codepipeline configuration I assume that you set up your codepipeline to monitor developer-001.  This means it will trigger the pipeline to kick off when a change happens to the branch, so any merge or commit would do that.  If you want it to monitor your dev branch than make sure you set that attribute.  Can you provide your configuration and I can give you a a better answer?

See picture below that's where you define the branch to monitor
[image]

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. You can [search for similar questions](/search), or refer to the related and linked questions on the right-hand side of the page to find an answer. If you have a related but different question, [ask a new question](/questions/ask), and include a link to this one to help provide context. See: [Ask questions, get answers, no distractions](/tour)

Comment: richard, i went back to update a screen shot for this question.  That was less than 5 minutes ago.  Appreciate the feedback